# C scientific notation exponent format

Tags: c, printf

Is it possible to control number of digits shown in exponent printed by scientific notation (`e`) of [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)?

This code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%6.3e", 403.0);
    return 0;
}
```

produces (depends on compiler/platform):

`4.030e+002` (`VS2010`) or `4.030e+02` (`gcc 4.3.4`) or even `4.030e+2`

The different number of digits in exponents can easily confuse a diff tool when comparing files generated on different platforms.

Comment: I would say that the first and last are bugs in the respective libraries, as [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (haven't checked the standard yet) states that "The exponent contains at least two digits, more digits are used only if necessary."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard actually specifies how many digits are to be in the exponent (WG14 N1570, §7.21.6.1/p8; N1256, §7.19.6.1/p8):

> The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent.

VS2010's implementation is nonconforming. They do provide a [library function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fatw238.aspx) to change the number of digits printed, which you can use inside a `#ifdef` wrapper.

Comment: Just a note that VS2010 `_set_output_format(_TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT)` do not work with `sprintf`, just with `printf` and `fprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with C `printf()`.

According to C99 standard doc 7.19.6.1 for `%e` and `%f`: `The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent. If the value is zero, the exponent is zero`

You could however, write your own wrapper function, where you calculate the base and exponent separately, to get the output in desired format.

Something like:

```
char* printexponent(double x)
{
    //calculate base here
    //calculate exponent here

    //create the floating point string and return it 
}
```

Or you could manipulate the output of the printf `%e` to create your own string.